# Photoshop: convert all caps text to lowercase

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, typesetting

I have a PSD file with a large block of text set in uppercase. Is there a way to convert selected text to lowercase? I've tried everything in the character panel, but nothing will change it to lowercase. I don't want to have to re-write the whole text!

Comment: Copy, paste in to another tool where converting to lowercase is easy to do, copy, paste back into Photoshop.

Comment: @DA01 hmm I was thinking Excel or a quick Ruby / Python script but if its sentences that could get complicated. Do you have any suggestion of such a tool? Might be worth leaving as an answer

Comment: @DA01, which tools would be good for that?

Comment: I think MS Word has this as an option. BBEdit does. Dreamweaver might have?

Comment: Even Illustrator!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible the text was created All Caps from the pull out on the Character panel. If so, select all the text unselect the All Caps. See image below.

Alternatively you can use this useful resource, and copy / paste the text from your PSD file into the site. You can then convert it to the type of case (Sentence case, lower case, Capitalized Case, etc) and copy / paste it back to your PSD file:

http://convertcase.net/

[image]

Comment: Just click on the TT 'all caps' box and it auto changes to Upper/lowercase